# DynamoDB replication across AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking for a better way to replicate data from one AWS account DynamoDB to another account.
I know this can be done using Lambda triggers and streams.

Is there something like Global tables which exist in AWS we can use for replication across accounts?

Comment: FYI for other readers (because I think you know it already), from [Global Tables: How It Works - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/V2globaltables_HowItWorks.html): "A global table is a collection of one or more replica tables, all owned by _a single AWS account_". I'm not familiar with a similar automated option for replicating DynamoDB tables between accounts. Using DynamoDB Streams would probably be the only option, but let's see if other people can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way for migrating data between accounts is using AWS Data pipeline. This process will essentially take a backup (export) of your DynamoDb table in Account A to a S3 bucket of account B via DataPipeline. Then, one more DataPipeline job in account B would import the data from S3 back to the provided DynamoDb table.

The step by step manual is given in this document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html.

Also you will need Cross-account access to the S3 bucket which you will be using to store your DynamoDB table data from account A, so the bucket or (the files) you are using must be shared between your account (A) and your destination account (B), till the migration gets completed.
Refer this doc for permissions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Another approach you can take is using script. There is no direct API for migration. You will have to use two clients, one for each account. One client will scan the data and other client could write that data into the table in another account.

Also I think they do have an import-export tool as mentioned in their AWSLabs repo. Although I have never tried this.
https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-import-export-tool